# Setting a Path as a Variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty new to the world of VBA, but I am having problem with a small part of a much larger code for an excel spreadsheet. My problem is that I am getting an "Invalid procedure call or argument" when trying to use a cell set as a variable and then plugging that variable into the path. It works when I set oFSO.GetFolder("Actual Path") as the actual path, but when I set a variable equal to a cell, which equals the path, it gives me this error. Thanks in advance!!

````
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim POSMVPath As Variant

Set POSMVPath = Range("C30").Value
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(POSMVPath)

    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "DeleteSheet"

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files

    Cells(i + 1, 1) = oFile.Name

    i = i + 1

Next oFile```
````

Comment: Remove the `Set` from `Set POSMVPath = Range("C30").Value`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I just tried that and I am still getting the same "Run-time error '5': Invalid Procedure Call or Argument" on the line with reads ```Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(POSMVPath)``` I printed the POSMV variable and it is reading it in correctly and strangely sometimes, if I run it as it's own procedure, it will make it the whole way through without any errors if I step through it, but it fails when I try to run it in one go.

Comment: Hey scratch that I'm an idiot. I wasn't activating the right sheet before that part of the macro. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon.
Dim POSMVPath As Variant
when you define this variable you must define ti as a range instead of a Variant.